# Open SharePoint 2013 list item on mouseover using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery

In my SharePoint 2013 list , I want to open the list item in a modal dialog box on mouseover . How can i use javascript to achieve this . I am at a very basic level in javascript , so please i need a detailed answer for this . thanks in advance friends.

Answer (score 1):

> I am at a very basic level in javascript , so please i need a detailed
>   answer for this

So you want us to do your job??

Do we get the paycheck as well then??

You have to put weeks of learning into it yourself.. just like the rest of us:

#### Read this explanation by Andrei Markeev:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/620110/sharepoint-client-side-rendering-list-views

To learn about Client Side Rendering (CSR) and change how a ListView is displayed in the browser

#### Then read this Microsoft documentation:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

*Learn* from them,  don't take the examples for granted, it is not always the best JavaScript

#### Then use this *best-thing-since-sliced-bread* tool (by Andrei Markeev) :

https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar

To add a (Chrome Extension) WYSIWYG CSR editor and not have to set those JSLinks manually

#### You can now apply all you learned and use this code:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-modal-dialog-pop-up-in-sharepoint-2016-and-office-365/

To open content in a SharePoint Modal Dialog